# Why isn't the method that implements a protocol in the child class being called?

Tags: swift3

This is new behavior I encountered while updating my project to swift 3. When implementing a method of the UITableViewDelegate in a "child" class like this example

```
class A: NSObject, UITableViewDelegate {
    var tableView = UITableView()
    override init() {
        super.init()
        tableView.delegate = self
    }
}

class B: A {
    var count = 0
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        count += 1
    }
}
```

The method `didSelectRowAt` never gets called:

```
let b = B()
b.tableView.delegate!.tableView?(b.tableView, didSelectRowAt: IndexPath())
b.count // => 0
```

However if I implement the method in the parent and override it in the child then it starts working:

```
class A: NSObject, UITableViewDelegate {
    var tableView = UITableView()
    override init() {
        super.init()
        tableView.delegate = self
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    }
}

class B: A {
    var count = 0
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        count += 1
    }
}

let b = B()
b.tableView.delegate!.tableView?(b.tableView, didSelectRowAt: IndexPath())
b.count // => 1
```

I tried to simplify the example more by providing my own protocol and "table" class, but I couldn't get it to behave the same way again. This leads me to believe that the observed behavior in this example is not expected and actually a bug.

Has anyone else encountered the same (or similar) issue? I figured it was worth asking in case this helps anyone.

Comment: Why does your tableview delegate have an instance of a table view? That doesn't make much sense

Answer (score 0):

For anyone landing here: Looks like this was a real bug that has been fixed by the swift team. For more info see https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2919